# How to create equal width solidgauge for any number of series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am facing some problem to create solidgauge chart using HighCharts library.

I want to make width of every series equal and also their background but unable to understand innerRadius, outerRadius, radius of data and pane background correctly.

It should be flexible with any container width.

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/SpiritualDixit/bypL5t33/)

JS:

```
function buildChartOptions(series)
    {
       var nextRadius = 50, dataRadiusDiff = 25, nextBgInnerRadius = 38, bgRadiusDiff = 24;
        this.options = {
            chart: {},
            title: {},
            tooltip: {},
            pane: {},
            yAxis: {},
            plotOptions: {},
            series: {},
        };

        this.options.chart = {
            type: 'solidgauge',
            marginTop: 50
        };

        this.options.title = {
            text: null,
            style: {
                fontSize: '24px',
            }
        };

        this.options.tooltip = {
            borderWidth: 0,
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            shadow: false,
            style: {
                fontSize: '12px'
            },
            pointFormat: '{series.name}<br><span style="padding:10px;font-size:2em; color: {point.color}; font-weight: bold">{point.y} %</span>',
            positioner: function (labelWidth, labelHeight) {
                return {
                    x: 200 - labelWidth / 2,
                    y: 180
                };
            }
        };

        var chartWidth = (100-(series.length * 8 )),
        borderWidth = (100 - 11.02 * series.length);
        chartWidth = chartWidth < 30 ? 35 : chartWidth;
        borderWidth = borderWidth < 10 ? 15: borderWidth;

        borderWidth = 34;

        console.log('chart ', chartWidth, 'border ', borderWidth);

        this.options.pane = {
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            size: Math.abs(chartWidth) + '%',
            background: []
        };

        this.options.yAxis = {};

        this.options.plotOptions = {
            solidgauge: {
                borderWidth: borderWidth + 'px',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                linecap: 'square',
                stickyTracking: true
            }
        };

        this.options.series = [];

        for(var i=0; i<series.length; i++)
        {
            this.options.series.push({
                name: series[i].name,
                borderColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                data:[{
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                    radius: nextRadius+'%',
                    innerRadius: nextRadius+'%',
                    y: (i*10)+20
               }]
            });


            nextRadius += dataRadiusDiff;

            this.options.pane.background.push({
                outerRadius: parseInt(nextBgInnerRadius + bgRadiusDiff) + '%',
                innerRadius: nextBgInnerRadius+'%',
                backgroundColor: Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i]).setOpacity(0.5).get(),
                borderWidth: 1,
                shape: 'arc'
            });

            nextBgInnerRadius += (bgRadiusDiff + 1);
        }

        this.options.series.reverse();
        this.options.pane.background.reverse();
        var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', this.options);
        return this.options;
    }


    var series = [
{name:'A',id :0, data:10, color:'#043310', bgcolor:'#033249'},
{name:'B',id :1, data:30, color:'#024230', bgcolor:'#134349'},
{name:'C',id :2, data:50, color:'#042210', bgcolor:'#022249'},
{name:'D',id :2, data:150, color:'#042210', bgcolor:'#022249'},
{name:'E',id :2, data:250, color:'#042210', bgcolor:'#022249'},
];/*
{name:'F',id :2, data:350, color:'#042210', bgcolor:'#022249'},
{name:'G',id :2, data:150, color:'#042210', bgcolor:'#022249'},
{name:'H',id :2, data:240, color:'#042210', bgcolor:'#022249'},
{name:'I',id :1, data:30, color:'#024230', bgcolor:'#134349'},
{name:'J',id :2, data:50, color:'#042210', bgcolor:'#022249'},
{name:'I',id :1, data:30, color:'#024230', bgcolor:'#134349'},
{name:'J',id :2, data:50, color:'#042210', bgcolor:'#022249'},
];*/

buildChartOptions(series);
```

Can some one help me with it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not require an extra calculation for a different container's width to apply equal `innerRadius`, `outerRadius` of all panes and `radius`, `innerRadius` of all series. If you want series and panes display with the same width and you want to set it dynamically, you can write a simple function and set min, max radius and caluculate radiusStep. For the reference, take a look at the example I posted below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Csolidgauge%3E.data.radius
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Csolidgauge%3E.data.innerRadius

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/wt5Lp09r/

Comment: Thanks you very much.